# Java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library when loading mp3 file

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, media

I'm new to java and I'm trying to make my javafx application play a sound. I'm not being able though to create a javafx.scene.media.Media object as I keep getting the exception.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\Cliente\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_252\jre\bin\glib-lite.dll
```

Here is the piece of code that is generating this error.

```
Media sound = new Media(new File("./data/audio/Bomb.mp3").toURI().toString());
```

I imagine that this is being generated by my uri being wrongly formatted but I can't see why this is different from tutorials I've seen. My audio file finds itself in /data/audio which is inside the root folder of the project. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which JVM and JDK are you using? Does the file `C:\Users\Cliente\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_252\jre\bin\glib-lite.dll` exist on your harddrive? What is your operating system (Windows, but which one)? Does the exception came with a stack trace? If so, please add it here! Have you access to other JDKs? Can you try your code with these?

Comment: As it relates to the music file, you need to determine if it is packaged with the jar or not and follow the answer for your case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347658/getting-a-mp3-file-to-play-using-javafx. If you know that it is packaged with the jar, the following is a great resource. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem has nothing to do with the creation of the `Media` object.

Amazon Corretto for Java 8 does not support JavaFX. Please, see the following [Github issue](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8/issues/26) and [this comment](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8/issues/26#issuecomment-658910915):

> Hi. The build of OpenJFX 8 in Corretto 8 is currently on life support and we only plan to apply security patches and critical fixes. Upstream, OpenJFX 8 is abandoned (see https://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx).

> The recommended way of using JavaFX is with Corretto 11 and pulling in OpenJFX separately e.g. with a Maven dependency. The latest version (currently 14) is compatible with Corretto 11.

> Closing this issue.

Please, follow the suggested approach, or use a different Java distribution instead.

Please, see also this [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750910/how-to-fix-unsatisfiedlinkerror) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876524/is-javafx-media-supported-by-corretto) SO questions, I hope they will be help.

Comment: thanks yes it  looks like it is the issue since i'm using JDK 8 which is old

Comment: You are welcome @Asmoun, thank you. I am happy to hear that the answer was helpful.

Comment: @Asmoun Just for clarification, I do not thing the problem is whether the JDK is old or not, it has to do with the Java 8 version of Amazon Corretto, but for Java 8 you can find other JVM distribution that should work properly as suggested in the above-mentioned issue as well. You can of course switch to a recent version of Amazon Corretto as also indicated in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Media sound = new Media(new File("./data/audio/Bomb.mp3").toURI().toString());
                                                                     ^ issue.
```

use

```
Media sound = new Media(new File("./data/audio/Bomb.mp3").toURI().getPath());
```

Comment: No. The `javafx.scene.media.Media` constructor takes a URI not a file path. If there is no scheme then it assumes the path is a _resource path_ (i.e. relative to the class-path).

Comment: well ... there go my dreams of acquiring 50 internet points ....

Comment: @EverNight no worries 50 points will split between you two , so you will have 25

Comment: Thanks @Asmoun , but my answer was besides the point. I don't think I should be getting any points for it. :) should'a probably spent more than 5 minutes checking the context out.  It's only fair the other guy gets 100%